# Android VBO / IBO not working correctly

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

Currently I am working on a 3D Game Engine for Android. The Project is just at the beginning, but there is a problem I cant' solve. 
I want to use VertexBufferObjects for rendering the models loaded form an .obj file. 
Here is the code

```
public class Mesh {

    private final int mBytesPerFloat = 4;

    private FloatBuffer vertices;
    private FloatBuffer normals;
    private IntBuffer faces;

    private int vertexBuffer;
    private int normalBuffer;
    private int indexBuffer;

    public Mesh(float[] vertices, float[] normals, int[] faces, int shaderProgram) {

        this.normals = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(normals.length * mBytesPerFloat)
                .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
                .asFloatBuffer();
        this.normals.put(normals).position(0);

        this.faces = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(faces.length * mBytesPerFloat)
                .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
                .asIntBuffer();
        this.faces.put(faces).position(0);

        this.vertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * mBytesPerFloat)
                .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
                .asFloatBuffer();
        this.vertices.put(vertices).position(0);

        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(8);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        IntBuffer buffer = bb.asIntBuffer();        
        GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, buffer);
        vertexBuffer = buffer.get(0);       

        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
        GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertices.capacity() * mBytesPerFloat, this.vertices, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(8);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        buffer = bb.asIntBuffer();      
        GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, buffer);
        normalBuffer = buffer.get(0);
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalBuffer);
        GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.normals.capacity() * mBytesPerFloat, this.normals, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(8);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        buffer = bb.asIntBuffer();      
        GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, buffer);
        indexBuffer = buffer.get(0);
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
        GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.faces.capacity() * mBytesPerFloat, this.faces, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    }

    public Mesh() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void render(int shaderProgram) {
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "vertex"), 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "vertex"));
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalBuffer);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "normal"), 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "normal"));
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);       
        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, vertices.capacity()/3, GLES20.GL_INT, faces);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I do not see anything. 
The problem is not the shader i am using (which I know is working correctly) and the modelview matrix and projection matrix are correct, so the object should be visible, if it is rendered which it isn't.
Has anyone an idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem like [`glDrawElements`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml) accepts `GL_INT` as data type, so maybe the `glDrawElements` call just fails (which could have easily been checking with some simple [`glGetError`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetError.xml) calls for the sake of debugging). Just try `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` instead (and maybe a `UIntBuffer` for `faces` or something similar, if that exists).

Maybe it doesn't even have `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` in ES and you need 2-byte `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT`s, but I'm not sure about that. But you definitely need an unsigned type (what sense does a signed type make for indices anyway? But ok, that's *Java*). Anyway, some `glGetError`s might do wonders here.